# Implementing MERGE INTO sql in pyspark

Tags: sql, merge, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How can problemmatically (pyspark) sql MERGE INTO statement can be achieved. I have two tables which I have table into temporary view using createOrReplaceTempView option. Then I tried using MERGE INTO statement on those two temporary views. But it is failing. The reason can be MERGE is not supported in SPARK SQL. Can some one give an hint how could a simple MERGE INTO SQL equivalent statement (something like below) can be implemented programmatically in pyspark.

```
MERGE INTO events
USING updates
ON events.eventId = updates.eventId
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET
    events.data = updates.data
WHEN NOT MATCHED
  THEN INSERT (date, eventId, data) VALUES (date, eventId, data)
```

Comment: Hi Kaushik, There is no direct approach to do Merge in spark. Though you can do it with normal sql logically using case approach.

Comment: Can you share an small example code

Answer (score 4):

Merge does not support directly but we if we are ok to overwrite the complete table then you can follow the approach.

```
hiveContext.sql("select * from events").registerTempTable("temp_events")
hiveContext.sql("select * from updates").registerTempTable("temp_updates")

hiveContext("""
select
case when b.eventId is null then a.date else b.date as date,
case when b.eventId is null then a.eventId else b.eventId end as eventId,
case when b.eventId is null then a.data else b.data as data
from
temp_events a
full outer join
temp_updates b
on a.eventId=b.eventId
""").registerTempTable("FinalData")

hiveContext.sql("INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table_name select * from FinalData")
```

Using the case, we are making sure if the data is available in new set then we are taking those values else we will be taking the older values.

Please check if this solution works for you.

Thanks,
Manu

Comment: Depends on data. Queries can be optimized by using bucketing or other approaches and with Spark we can take that risk. I wrote the code which process10 million data and it has multiple other queries as well. It takes 5-7 mins.

Comment: Which version of hive and Spark you are using? With Orc update command works. So if that works the we can update and for new records we can find out by join and then we can union the records. That can be an efficient solution. I will check and test it tomorrow and will update.

Comment: we are using Spark 2.2.0 and we are using PARQUET format table not ORC

Comment: How the UPDATE part of MERGE statement is handled in the above query?

Comment: In case of insert or update case the b.eventid won't be null so we handled that case. If the record is not available in updates then it would be null and in that case we will be picking the data from the older records. One more thing, I just wanted to inform that there is key available already so I did not included hash function otherwise we could include the hash function as well to optimize the performance.

Comment: Latest versions of hive are coming up with update, merge and PLHQL kind of approaches. You can explore that as well. Not sure if they will work with hive.execution.engine=spark. If that works then problem can be solved.